# Change the year of the whole site

Tags: date-time

I want to change the year of the whole site, temporarily, from 2018 to 2019.

So the year of `the_time()` has to be 2019.

There are no plugins which can do this...

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this temporarily that means you want to be able to switch back later, right? That in turn means you don't want to change the values in the database. So you want `the_time` to change after it has retrieved the value from the database, but before it is presented to the user. Luckily [`the_time`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_time/) has a filter for that. Like this

```
add_filter ('the_time','wpse303207_change_year');

function wpse303207_change_year ($time) {
   // do your thing
   }
```

Because `the_time` returns a string that depends on the [time format](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) you have chosen, you'll have to sort out yourself how to use `str_replace` to change the date inside the time string.

This would also work for [`the_date`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/), by the way.